# How do I retrieve variation name from Variation id in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

I use the following function call to get a product variations,

```
$available_variations = $product->get_available_variations();
```

And in the returned $available_variations I have all the variations.

I am given the variation_id, and I do not have the knowledge of the name of the attribute, which in this case is country-of-origin, so how do i retrieve the attribute values, which are Hong Kong and Singapore in this case?

Below is the dump of above $available_variations,

```
[18-Mar-2014 17:04:20 UTC] Array
(
[variation_id] => 2968
[attributes] => Array
    (
        [attribute_pa_country-of-origin] => hong-kong
    )

[image_src] => 
[image_link] => 
[image_title] => 
[image_alt] => 
[price_html] => <span class="price"><span class="amount">SGD$15</span></span>
[availability_html] => 
[sku] => 
[weight] =>  kg
[dimensions] => 
[min_qty] => 1
[max_qty] => 0
[backorders_allowed] => 
[is_in_stock] => 1
[is_downloadable] => 
[is_virtual] => 
[is_sold_individually] => no
)

[18-Mar-2014 17:04:20 UTC] Array
(
[variation_id] => 2969
[attributes] => Array
    (
        [attribute_pa_country-of-origin] => singapore
    )

[image_src] => 
[image_link] => 
[image_title] => 
[image_alt] => 
[price_html] => <span class="price"><span class="amount">SGD$12</span></span>
[availability_html] => 
[sku] => 
[weight] =>  kg
[dimensions] => 
[min_qty] => 1
[max_qty] => 0
[backorders_allowed] => 
[is_in_stock] => 1
[is_downloadable] => 
[is_virtual] => 
[is_sold_individually] => no
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but just incase someone needs this in the future and comes across this post, the correct way is.

```
echo $available_variations[0][attributes][attribute_pa_country-of-origin];
echo $available_variations[1][attributes][attribute_pa_country-of-origin];
```